# Array name when using Jquery to GET with datatype JSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, handlebars.js

So, I started using Handlebars.js template to dispaly html code on success from a Jquery GET request. I then get an Array from my Controller (who gets it from my Model /database). In Handlebars I have to use the Array name to loop through it. I pass this Array using dataype JSON, and using `json_encoding($array}` in my Controller.

The problem is my Array don't seem to get an array name, so I dont have an array name to refer to.

Code in Model:

```
public function getAllUserInfo() {
   $this->selStmt->execute();
   return $this->selStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Code in Controller:

```
private function getUserInfo() {
   $userInfo = $GLOBALS["userModel"];
   $userModel = $userInfo->getSearchResult();     
   $data = json_encode($userModel);
   echo $data;
}
```

Code in View (Jquery):

```
$(function () {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '?page=getUserInfo',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) { 
          createHTML(data);
          $.each(data, function(i, item){          
              displayUsers(item);  
        });
      }
   });
});
```

displayUsers function is the handlebar function.

My problem is that the array I GET when loading page looks like this:

```
[{"userID":"19","name":"Testbruker2","username":"Test2","password":"test123","userLevel":"user","image":"tafjord.jpg","lastLogin":null,"email":"test@test.no"},{"userID":"20","name":"Testbruker3","username":"Test3","password":"test123","userLevel":"user","image":"tafjord.jpg","lastLogin":null,"email":"test@test.no"}]
```

And i want something like this:

```
{ 
  Pets:   [
      {
        "name": "Meowsy",
        "species" : "cat",
        "foods": {
          "likes": ["tuna", "catnip"],
          "dislikes": ["ham", "zucchini"]
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Barky",
        "species" : "dog",
        "foods": {
          "likes": ["bones", "carrots"],
          "dislikes": ["tuna"]
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Purrpaws",
        "species" : "cat",
        "foods": {
          "likes": ["mice"],
          "dislikes": ["cookies"]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

In my handlebar container I have to write:

```
{{#each ARRAYNAME}}
//code here
{{/each}}
```

but i dont have a Array name to refer to..

Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do the trick

```
$data = json_encode(array("DesiredArrayName" => $userModel));
```